# WPF Button multiple text lines access

Tags: c#, wpf

I made style for button

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonList"
       TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Aqua" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                    <TextBlock x:Name="AText" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="BText" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

How can I sett the Text of "Atext" textblock and "BText" textblock seperate from codebehind?

Comment: why not define a usercontrol instead? then you could have access to `usercontrol1.InnerControl2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

Create a AttachedProperty for Button(or you can create a customControl based on Button) named with ContentB.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="AText" Text={TemplateBinding Content}/>
<TextBlock x:Name="BText" Text={TemplateBinding ap:ContentB} HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

In cs code,you can access Button.Content and Button.ContentB

2.Another method:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="AText" Text={TemplateBinding Content,Converter={StaticSource ContentConverter},ConverterParameter=1}/>
<TextBlock x:Name="BText" Text={TemplateBinding Content,Converter={StaticSource ContentConverter},ConverterParameter=2} HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

ContentConverter.cs Code:

```
internal class ContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string valuestring)
        {
            return valuestring.Split(',')[(int)parameter-1];
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

oh,You need to use a separator e.g. commas to separate the two text pieces

Comment: Thanks for anwer! It seems like a good solution but I have error "XDG0006" and "MC3029" in my style XAML. any tip / solution to that?

Comment: For Method1："ap:" is only a sample.It meams the namespace of ContentB.you shuold create ContentB firstly.

Comment: For Method2: ContentConverter should be decleared as a resource with specific key